# How to show only one level sub category?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

> I am building a real estate website so i have many category 3 to 4
>   level child category but my requirement is to show only one level sub
>   category of the parent category eg **sub1 ,sub2 and sub3** only see the structure I'm having category like this

```
- cat1
    - sub1
       - secondsub1
- cat2
    - sub2
      - secondsub2
- cat3
   - sub3
      - secondsub3



$categories = get_terms(
                    'category', 
                    array('hide_empty' => 0,'parent' => 0,'number' =>3,'order'=> 'ASC') 
                        );
foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $catName= $category->term_id;

<?php echo get_cat_name( $catName ); // this is the main category ?>

<!-- subcategory code starts here-->

        $args = array(
                    'type' => 'post',
                    'child_of' => $catName,
                    'parent' => get_query_var(''),
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'hide_empty' => 0,
                    'hierarchical' => 1,
                    'exclude' => '',
                    'include' => '',
                    'number' => '5',
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'pad_counts' => true );
                    $categories = get_categories($args);
                    foreach($categories as $category) {
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id )?>" title="View posts in <?php echo $category->name?>"><?php $category->name;?></span><!--these are the sub category-->
 }
}
```

> In result i get under **cate1 sub1->secondsub1** because
>   **secondsub1** is also child to **cat1** but i only want **sub1** how can i accomplish that ? any suggestions

Answer (score 4):

**Use `parent` instead of `child_of`:**

> `parent` (int|string) Parent term ID to retrieve direct-child terms of.

Source: [#parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/#parameters)

Comment: thanks for answer i just forgot i should not use child_of :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use wp_list_categories( ([Developer Wordpress Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories)) to get subcategories for each of your category. Im not sure about efficiency of this usage, but give it a try.

So in your code that would be here:

```
<!-- subcategory code starts here-->
wp_list_categories( array(
    'child_of'    => $category->term_id,
    'depth'       => 1    
) );
```

---

After some reading I found other solution, so you would use:

```
    $args = array('parent' => $category->term_id);
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach($categories as $category) { 
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id )?>" title="View posts in <?php echo $category->name?>"><?php $category->name;?></span><!--these are the sub category-->
    }
```

Also take care with using '$categories' twice, this may get a little bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i do not want to use the wp_list_categories second answer you have given works thanks :)